# Matlab: Loop for reading NetCDF files and then save a specific variable of each one in the workplace as a separated variable- How to write code?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, netcdf

I have a simple question that makes me confusing.
I have 34 NetCDF files. each of them has four variable ( latitude, longitude, time, and precipitation)
I want to write a code for reading the fourth variable (Precipitation) of each file and then save one by one in the workplace.
In the end, I would like to have something like this:
precipitation1
precipitation2
precipitation3
.
.
.
precipitation34
just if is matter precipitation variable of these NetCDF has three dimensions (lat*lon*time)

here's my code so far:

```
clc
clear
format compact
close all
% Specify the folder where the files are.
myFolder = 'F:\MATLAB WORKS\code desktops\CPC Netcdfs\testa';
% Check to make sure that folder actually exists.  Warn user if it doesn't.
if ~isdir(myFolder)
  errorMessage = sprintf('Error: The following folder does not exist:\n%s', myFolder);
  uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
  return;
end
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.nc'); 
theFiles = dir(filePattern);
% Loop for each nc-file
for i = 1:length(theFiles)
  baseFileName = theFiles(i).name;
  fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
    ncdisp(ncfiles(i).name) ;
     ncid=netcdf.open(fullFileName, 'NC_NOWRITE');
     precipiation = ncread(filename,'precip'); %reading the main variable
     netcdf.close(ncid);
end
```

this code result this error:

> Undefined variable "ncfiles" or class "ncfiles".

Comment: The variable `ncfiles` is not defined anywhere, you probably meant `theFiles`?

Comment: oh thanks. I modified this by theFiles. but after run the code it's gave me another error:
`Error using netcdflib
The NetCDF library encountered an error during execution of 'inqVar'
function - 'Variable not found (NC_ENOTVAR)'.
Error in netcdf.inqVar (line 26)
[varname,xtype,dimids,natts] = netcdflib('inqVar', ncid, varid);
Error in netcdf.getVar (line 109)
    [~,xtype] = netcdf.inqVar(ncid,varid);`

Comment: Don’t make a different variable for each data set, use a single cell array to hold them all. You’d have `precipitation{1}` instead of `precipitation1`. All your code will be simpler and faster.